# Linq to xml combine values

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

Consider the following MediaObject class

```
Public Class MediaObject
     Public Path as String
     Public File as String
     Public Sub New(_path as String, _file as String)
         Path = _path
         File = _file
     End Sub
End Class
```

I have the following XML (myxml):

```
<records>
  <media>
    <path>\\first\path</path>
    <file>firstfile</file>
  </media>
  <media>
    <path>\\second\path</path>
    <file>secondfile</file>
  </media>
<records>
```

To get a list of MediaObjects I use this :

```
    Dim mobjects As New List(Of MediaObject)
    Dim x As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(myxml)

    mobjects = (From m In x.<records>.<media> Select media = New MediaObject(m.<path>.Value, m.<file>.Value)).ToList()
```

All is fine.
But now consider this new XML (where second file is an alternate of the first one) :

```
<records>
  <media>
    <path>\\first\path</path>
    <file>firstfile</file>
    <path>\\second\path</path>
    <file>secondfile</file>
  </media>
</records>
```

I can easily get either of properties but not both, i.e.

```
    Dim mobjects As New List(Of MediaObject)
    Dim x As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(myxml)

    'here get only the paths
    Dim r = (From m In x.<records>.<media> Select media = (From t In m.<path> Select New MediaObject(t.Value, Nothing)).ToList()).ToList()

    mobjects = r(0)
```

How would I go to create a list of MediaObjects in this context ?
(let's consider path and file values in the xml are in sequence and go 2 by 2)

Thanks!

**UPDATE**:
Sorry I wasn't precise enough.
Here is the real world scenario.
There can many paths and files and it's guaranteed

- paths come before files
- there is the same number of paths and files
- all paths come first, then all files

Sample:

```
    <records>
      <media>
        <some_tags />
        <path>\\first\path</path>
        <path>\\second\path</path>
        <might_be_something_here />
        <file>firstfile</file>
        <file>secondfile</file>
        <more_tags />
      </media>
    </records>
```

PS: I cannot change the XML, which comes from another system...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're simply pairing up every nth path and file, you can do this:

```
Dim paths = doc...<path>
Dim files = doc...<file>
Dim query = paths.Zip(files, Function(p, f)
    New MediaObject(CType(p, String), CType(f, String))
)
```

You don't even have to worry about possible elements that are in between, they'll simply be ignored.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Sorry I wasn't precise enough, I updated my question. Still, I am quite sure this is the way to go, using maybe NodesAfterSelf and selecting the Nth file tag.

Comment: So you're pairing every nth path and file, no problem.

Comment: Thanks that's perfect !